# how can i control jquery UI Accordian with external anchor or button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I control jQuery UI Accordion with external anchor or button?

Suppose I use:

```
<script>
 $function(){
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true
    });
});  
</script>
```

With this HTML:

```
    <div id="accordion">

<div>
<h3><a href="#"><b>tab1</b></a></h3>
    <div>
    <p>Some text here 1</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div>
     <h3><a href="#"><b>tab 2</b></a></h3>
<div>
     <p>some text here 2</p> 
     </div>
</div>

</div>
```

How can I control or trigger or open these with external anchor or button?

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
<h3><a href="#"><b>tab 2</b></a></h3>
```

to,

```
<h3><a name="tab2" href="#tab2"><b>tab 2</b></a></h3>
```

Then code your link like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/page/#tab2">Click here to see Tab 2</a>
```

I've just done this on a site today. The problem I'm having is that the page links to the correct anchor point and then opens the accordian, meaning the user is no longer at the correct anchor point.